# Flutter, No MediaQuery widget ancestor found

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error:

```
No MediaQuery widget ancestor found.
```

and my Code is:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Die Sache",
      theme: ThemeData(
          elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        fixedSize: Size(0.3 * screenWidth, 0.2 * screenheight),
      ))),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`MediaQuery.of(context)` Only accessible inside `Material` widget. So you can do this:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var themeData;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: themeData,
      title: "Die Sache",
      home: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        double screenheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

        double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        if (themeData == null) {
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            setState(() {
              themeData = ThemeData(
                  elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                fixedSize: Size(0.3 * screenWidth, 0.2 * screenheight),
              )));
            });
          });
        }
        return MyHomePage();
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did not work. It returns to its default status, when moving to another screen

Comment: @MhmdKhatib I updated my answer, check it out.